# AngularJS successful PUT followed by unwanted GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, put

In summary, in my AngularJS page I PUT and receive answers.  Now Angular is doing something that puts the form fields in the URL and performing what amounts to a GET.

In detail, my form is like:

```
<body ng-app="userApp">
  <div ng-controller="userController">
  <form id="userForm" modelAttribute="userAttribute" action="">
      <table>
          <tr><td><input type="text" id="userName" ng-model="user.userName" /></td></tr>
          <tr><td><input type="text" id="fullName" ng-model="user.fullName" /></td></tr>
          <tr><td><button type="submit" ng-click="submitForm()">Submit</button></td></tr>
      </table>
  </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

And my controller is:

```
angular.module("userApp", [])
    .controller("userController", ['$scope', '$http', '$document', function ($scope, $http, $document) {
        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.msg = "";

        $http.get('/sg/user/' + userId)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.user = data;
                $scope.error = "";

                if(typeof $scope.user._id === "undefined") {
                    $scope.formTask = "Create New";
                    $document.prop('title', 'Create User');
                } else {
                    $scope.formTask = "Edit";
                    $document.prop('title', '"Edit User');
                }

            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.user = {};
                $scope.error = data;
            });

        $scope.submitForm = function()
        {
            $http.put('/sg/user/' + userId, $scope.user)
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config)
                {
                    $scope.msg = data;
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config)
                {
                    $scope.msg = "SUBMIT ERROR";
                });
        };
    }]);
```

When I call the page:

```
http://MYAPP/sg/user/edit/2
```

the page displays properly, filled with user #2 data.  When I click on "Submit" the $http.put() is called OK, and (using the debugger) the .success() function is called, the "data" being filled with my "User #2 updated OK" message.

Once success() exits the URL bar is filled with this:

```
http://MYAPP/sg/user/edit/2?userName=SecondUser&fullName=Second+User
```

and the .controller() is called again.  As though the page were told to refresh, except that the form fields are filled like I sent out a GET.

What am I missing here?

TIA,
Jerome.

Comment: It's not angular, it just your HTML. Submit buttons still submit even if they are decorated with `ng-click`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using ng-click, but there's nothing to stop your button's default action, which is to submit the form.

Use the following instead.

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm()" ...>
```

Or change the button's `type="submit"` to `type="button"`.

Comment: Oops... I thought that I removed the type="submit" from that button.  I changed it as you mentioned and I get perfect results.  Thank you for your watchful eyes!